# Initiate call in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working on a Windows Phone 7 app and I want to give the option for the user to make a call. i.e How can I initiate a call when the user press a "call" button in my app? Looks like that API is not yet exposed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API you want is [PhoneCallTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask(v=VS.92).aspx)  Note that many of the external actions your app can initiate are in the [Microsoft.Phone.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=VS.92).aspx) namespace.